# How to apply css to multiple controls with same prefix in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

How can i apply the css to multiple controls in jquery ? Controls prefix is same.

I have tried this so far but it is not working;

```
var id = '#myorders_ctl' + cntrlId + '_';
 $(id + 'spanUpdateOrderItem', id + 'btnMinusOrderItem', id + 'btnAddOrderItem').css({ 'display': 'none' });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ids all need to be in a single selector string:

```
var id = '#myorders_ctl' + cntrlId + '_';
$(id + 'spanUpdateOrderItem,' + id + 'btnMinusOrderItem,' + id + 'btnAddOrderItem').hide();
```

I'd also suggest you research DOM traversal and common classes as incremental id attributes are an anti-pattern and lead to needlessly verbose logic, like the above.